# Remove noise from a rectangular wave matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, noise

I have some recordings (from 16:00PM to 16:00PM) where ones indicate some kind of noise and zeros indicate quite moments. The following code tries to replicate these recordings.

```
dt = datenum('00:02:00','HH:MM:ss') - datenum('00:01:00','HH:MM:ss'); 
time_begin = datenum('00:00:00','HH:MM:ss');
time_end = datenum('24:00:00','HH:MM:ss');
time = repmat(cellstr(datestr(time_begin:dt:time_end,'HH:MM:ss')),2,1);

loudness = ones(1,numel(time));
quiet_start = [1489 1737];
quiet_end = [1603 1906];

for i = 1: numel(quiet_start)
   loudness(quiet_start(i):quiet_end(i))=0; 
end

time = time(961:2400);
loudness = loudness(961:2400);


figure
plot(loudness)
ylim([0 3])
```

[image]

I know that in the interval 16:00PM - 16:00PM there should be only 1 "bout" of zeros. Here (if you plot `loudness`) you can see that there are 2 bouts of zeros.

I have 2 possibilities:

1. remove one of the two bouts of zeros
2. remove the bout of ones in the middle

Is there any measure that I can use to take this decision? I.e. Do I make a bigger error converting ones to zeros or viceversa?

There are 2 (or more) bouts of zeros because of some errors in the recordings...but for sure there should be only one. I would like to remove the bouts in order to "modify" the system as less as possible. For instance: in this case I would remove the first bout of zeros since it is the smallest, but what to do if there are more than 2 bouts? Is there any algorithm that deals with this kind of problems?

Comment: Hi, at least to me, the question is still unclear. You only want one bout of zeroes, and you have two; why are there two? How can you just remove one, what is the purpose of doing so? Others may find it easier to help if they understand it a bit better (or perhaps I am rather dense!).

Comment: No you are totally right... I will try to explain better: There are 2 (or more) bouts of zeros because of some errors in the recordings...but for sure there should be only one. I would like to remove the bouts in order to "modify" the system as less as possible. For instance: in this case I would remove the first bout of zeros since it is the smallest, but what to do if there are more than 2 bouts? Is there any algorithm that deals with this kind of problems?

Comment: I refer to your latest edit (rev 4): This depends on what *you* want the algorithm to do in those cases. From the information given in the question I cannot say what is the best. We don't know what you want to do after processing your data nor we know more about the actual data itself.

Comment: OK you can see the problem like this... I assume that zeros are periods of time in which someone is sleeping and ones timeframes in which someone is awake....in a "normal" scenario this person goes to bed only once per day. I am trying to estimate how long this person sleeps. (I know it won't be accurate, but I would like to have an estimation based on these audio and corrupted recordings).

Comment: ps I know that this person didn't wake up in the meantime (i.e. there should be only 1 bout of zeros)